# Vb.net + magento + quickbooks

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, quickbooks

i am going to develop a windows form application in visual studio using vb.net 3.5.
The application will be have a very big backend database needing many tables and over 20k records. The application will b installed on company's LAN and will be used by at most 6 people at the same time.

I am not sure what would be the best way to develop this, i have a couple of questions, i will appreciate if some1 can answer them and point me to the right direction.

1. What would be the best back-end database to use - Sql server or access would be fine ?
2. Can vb.net connect to quickbooks or magento database to update records, edit them or exchange information from the application. (i will be building a windows form application)

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Don't use Access. You can get SQL Express edition for free.
2. You can read and update directly in Magento's MySql database.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access can handle your data needs. We've as many as 25 users on an Access database with very large tables. Performance is not bad if it's properly indexed. However if you can afford it, SQL Server is a much better solution in terms of performance, capacity, backup, maintenance, monitoring and analysis, just about everything.

We were frustrated by the fact that you need to get everyone out of the Access db in order to secure a backup. If you copy it while people are accessing it, the file may not be internally consistent.

Yes Quickbooks has an API that you can access via VB. I've done a lot of custom app development with QB via VB.NET.

Magento's API is accessible by VB.NET in theory, however a lot of people have a hard time with it and their isn't a lot of sample code around.

Comment: Hey Max, thanks for your answer. What problems am i going to face with magento and are there any workarounds ?? Magento is really important to me.

Comment: maybe this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088459/how-to-call-the-magento-api-from-vb-net

I haven't had time to work on my magento app lately. Will get back on it in a few weeks. Maybe we can keep in touch and share progress.